# show() Not Working With Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an easy bit of coding, but something's there that i am doing wrong.I just can't figure it out.

```
#div {
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
function show() {
    var class = 1;
    $("#div." + class).show("slow");    
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div" class="1">John</div>
<div id="div" class="2">Tanner</div>
<input type="button" onclick="show()" />
```

Here I am trying to 'show()' a `div` of specific class.
The problem is, this code works fine for `class="1"`. But when I change `var class` to `2`, it stops working.

Comment: You have duplicate IDs. That's bad in itself.

Comment: your html is semantically incorrect

Comment: @ElzoValugi: When saying something like that, always elaborate.

Comment: @Cerbrus you are right http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: @ElzoValugi: way better ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A class can't be just a number. Rename the class to `$("#div." + "name"+class)`